# Next JS Error product.map Is Not a Function

Tags: dictionary, next.js, jsx

Hello everyone i have a question according to my case, i have

1. index.js code bellow :

```
    export default function Home({ productList }) {
          return (
            <div className={styles.container}>
              <Head>
                <title>OlResto UI Design With Next JS</title>
                <meta name="description" content="This is stunning website build using next js" />
                <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
              </Head>
              <Featured />
              <ProductList  productList={ productList } />
            </div>
          );
    };
    
    export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
        const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/products");
        return {
            props: {
                productList: res.data
            }
        }
    };
```

the second one i have file call ProductList.jsx
code below:

```
    const ProductList = ({ productList }) => {
      return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <h1 className={styles.title}>THE BEST PIZZA IN TOWN</h1>
            <p className={styles.desc}>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint, nemo at, labore porro reiciendis rem ad tempora blanditiis adipisci a eum animi obcaecati, dignissimos non perspiciatis natus corrupti consectetur libero.</p>
            <div className={styles.wrapper}>
              {productList.map(product => (
                 <ProductCard key={product._id} product={product} />
              ))}
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default ProductList;
```

Those files produce an error like this :

```
    TypeError: productList.map is not a function
    <div className={styles.wrapper}>
    {productList.map(product => (
                ^
    <ProductCard key={product._id} product={product} />
          ))}
      </div>
```

Sorry if my question messed up, hope you guys can help my problem, thank you in advance

Comment: In ProductList.jsx add a line to debug what productList is: `console.log('product list is', productList)`

Comment: Please check whether productList is an array. If it's getting undefined in any scenario then use like `productList && productList.map(...`

Comment: postman result : ```{
    "success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "6312e514b4227a95978b77da",
            "title": "pizza 77 merdeka",
            "desc": "Pizza terlezat yang pernah ada di indonesia",
            "img": "/images/featured-image-2.png",
            "prices": [
                90000,
                125000,
                175000
            ],
            "extraOptions": [],
            "createdAt": "2022-09-03T05:24:36.719Z",
            "updatedAt": "2022-09-03T05:24:36.719Z",
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}```

Comment: the data was an object what should i do to render as an array?

Comment: If the data is an object then you don't need to map over it. Just use the fields you need from the object directly.

Comment: i just wrong put my function position, i am using getServerSideProps with the axios, this case was solved, the previous i am using export default function, and then i changed that function in to arrow function, with that way i solved my problem, anyway thank you for your respond